# jQuery | Ajax, How to manipulate the array key from the received data in the external PHP file?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a script where ajax is being used to send password to a PHP file. The PHP file
then checks if the password is correct and sends back a data of array with a link and
succes code. When the data is received, I can clearly see the keys and values when I
alert it, but how do I manipulate the key to get the value from it?

See below for an example how I use to communicate jQuery Ajax with PHP:

jQuery Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: { pass: $("#pass-field").val() }
    }).done(function(data) {

        if(data.link != ""){
            alert("Link: " + data.link);
        }           
    });
```

PHP:

```
    if(strtolower($retrieved_password) == $original_password){
        echo json_encode(array("link" => "personal/cv.doc", "success" => "true")); 
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("link" => "", "success" => "false")); 
    }
?>
```

When I alert data.link I get to see the following code:

```
function link() {
    [native code]
}
```

Comment: Try using `console.log(data)` to see how the object is structured. That may help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Can you use console.log and a web developer tool instead of alert()?

Comment: I really don't know what you want to see. Instead of me saying anything, just go to my website to test it out please. In the home page, go look for a hyperlink where it says the following: 
Click here to download my resume.
http://www.xarialon.com/

Comment: when you click on the word here, a box will pop out and ask for a password. When you enter anything, you will see the code as mentioned before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the response has `text/html` type on it.

The `data` variable in your `done` callback is of type String

You should do `eval` on it to turn it into an object.

Something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    }).done(function(data) {
        var dataObj = {};
        eval ("dataObj = " + data); 
        console.log([dataObj]);         
    });
```

The best solution of course should be to return a response of type `text/json`.

This will make the data object of type `object`.

Anyway - you should make your callbacks support both types like so

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    }).done(function(data) {
        var dataObj = null;

        switch ( typeof(data) ) {
            case "object" : { dataObj = data; break; }
            case "string" : { eval ("dataObj = " + data); break; }
            default : { throw "unsupported type [" + typeof(data) + "]"  }
        }

             //... more code here       
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, this definitely did help me out! Instead of using eval, I used the following code to solve the problem:

var obj2 = JSON.parse(data);

This method is a must to parse a string to object.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you might use it:

- PHP

```php
<?php

    ...

    if (strtolower($retrieved_password) === $original_password) {
        // Use 'print json_encode(array(...));' if your PHP version is less than 5.4.
        print json_encode([
            'link'       => 'personal/cv.doc',
            'success'    => 'true',
        ]);
    } else {
        // Use 'print json_encode(array(...));' if your PHP version is less than 5.4.
        print json_encode([
            'link'       => '',
            'success'    => 'false',
        ]);
    }

    ...

?>
```

- jQuery

```js
...

$.ajax({
    'data':       {
        'password': $('#password_input').val()
    },
    'success':    function (json_data) {
        if (json_data['success'] !== 'false') {
            alert(json_data['link']);
        }
    },
    'type':       'POST',
    'url':        '/path/to/php_script.php'
});

...
```

This should work properly if `json_data` is being returned properly in the AJAX call. If it doesn't work, try changing `alert(json_data['link']);` to `console.log(json_data['link']);` and check your console. You probably want to this in Chrome or Safari as the developer tools are better on them, in my opinion. You can even try taking a screenshot of the output and add it to your post, so we can see how the data is coming back to you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it soon and mark correct when it works. ;)

Comment: To clarify, the big change here is from using a `deferred.done()` (which will not have the callback data you're looking for), to using `.ajax()`'s success setting

Comment: Nope, it still has the same result here. Click the link to view the image => 
[link](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/8933/parseerror.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it appears that the object return is in the following format.

> {"link": "","success": "false"}

To access the object's property values use the following.

`data.link` and/or `data.success` (`objectName.property`)

By the way, the `personal/cv.doc` is not truly protected. I was able to download it without the password based on what you put here.